# Python Folium tooltip permament

Tags: python, leaflet, marker, folium

I have made a app with Folium that create a Leaflet map as a html.

```
m=Folium.Map(location=[46.216, -124.1280],zoom_start=10)
ID="test"
folium.Marker(location=[46.216, -124.1280], tooltip=ID).add_to(m)
```

The marker will then be shown when dragging over the marker with the mouse, however I want to see the tootlip/ID of the marker permament. Can this be done in Folium?

I know leaflet have a bindtooltip options with a permament=True function, im looking for something similar for folium if someone knows :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the `Tooltip` class from  `folium` :

```
folium.Marker(location=[46.216, -124.1280], tooltip=folium.Tooltip("test", permanent=True)).add_to(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! it worked! Its tho abit large. Any tips/workaround on how to make the show tooltip permament toggleable? Thought of clustring the markers, but want to see if there is any other way around

[Pictures of markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOOT0.png)